# How to preload mp3 files

Tags: jquery, mp3, preload

I have about 50 sentences on each page and clicking on each of them a specific short mp3 (200-300KB) is playing.

```
<p class='sent' id='01/01.mp3'>some text</p>
<p class='sent' id='01/02.mp3'>some text</p>
<p class='sent' id='01/03.mp3'>some text</p>
....
```

js

```
$(".sent").click(function() {
abc=$(this).attr('id');
$('#player').html("<embed src=\""+abc+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"" + loop +"\" />");
});
```

I prefer this solution over `html5 audio tag` because of firefox/chrome compatibility, i.e. I don't need to convert a lot of files from `mp3` to `ogg`, but downside is that mp3 files are not preloaded, so there is a huge silence between clicking and playing.

Any solution to preload mp3 files ?
Or, maybe a better complete solution ?

Comment: I would recommend using html5 audio, or using an mp3 loaded through flash.  Both techniques have methods to preload mp3.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your jquery script, uses html5 audio tag properties.
you can try the preload property. preload = auto;

EDIT : By the way, this property says to start loading the file as soon as page starts to load
If you want to check if the file has loaded first and then play it, you can use the on event.

Comment: MentalRay, I will try, but I think that `embedding` an object is another story from the native `html5 audio`.

Comment: @MentalRay, it uses the embed tag, not html5 audio

Comment: @user120242 hmmm because of all these compatibility issues, and the fact you need preload, why don't you give a try to jPlayer?

Comment: @MentalRay, oh, I wasn't the one that asked the question.  I was just remarking that this does not actually answer the question.